# Laravel `select x as y` not working as expected?

Tags: php, laravel, orm

I am using the following syntax and getting empty records as a result:

```
return ModelName::select('some_real_column as desired_name')->get()->toJson();
```

What I get is:

```
[[], [], [], ... []]
```

If I do:

```
return ModelName::select('some_real_column')->get()->toJson();
```

It returns actual values.

Comment: I tried both suggestions but I keep getting [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]

Answer (score 1):

```
return ModelName::select(DB::raw('some_real_column as desired_name'))->get()->toJson();
```

Comment: I upvoted but I still get the same array of empty arrays. Very strange.

Comment: Have you tried enabling database debug to log the query actually being executed?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `selectRaw` method:

```
return ModelName::selectRaw('some_real_column as desired_name')->get()->toJson();
```

Comment: I see the same results?

Comment: I guess the only apparent solution is to use an array_map or something of that nature and manually mutate the key values.

Comment: @Zehelvion - What do you get when you run this query directly in your DB: `SELECT some_real_column as desired_name FROM table_name`?

Comment: @Zehelvion - What do you get for `ModelName::selectRaw('some_real_column as desired_name')->toSql()`?

Comment: Wait! I found something interesting. It seems to work fine when the table name is on the default db schema (in the connection). I am thinking there is a bug when the table name is not of the default schema and that is causing the problem?

Comment: I did this with no improvement:

    return ModelName::on('connection')->selectRaw('column_name as another_name')->get();